# How do I remove these wrinkles and small bumps in mesh after subdividing?

Tags: subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

[image]

I'm trying to subdivide a ripped game model for 3D printing. I end up with wrinkles and small bumps when I use the subdivision surface modifier. I converted triangles to quads via the face drop-down menu before subdividing, however, some triangles still remain. How do I work around this to remove the wrinkles? (Assuming the wrinkles are caused by the remaining triangles)

[image: Subdivided mesh]

[image: Unsubdivided mesh]

Comment: Hello and welcome. From your image, it looks like you have triangles, but it's hard to tell, the image is a bit far. But if you do have, then that could be the main issue

Comment: I would just model it again. It's quite easy.  But can you share your model?https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: did you try remesh modifier?

Comment: @Harry McKenzie I have uploaded my blender file. Could you please explain how to re-model as I am very new to Blender and I can't really make sense of the videos on YouTube.

Comment: @Chris Yeah I tried the remesh modifier

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your geometry to a perfect quad topology with the following steps for each star wing/corner. This will also serve as a good exercise.

Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and go to menu *Face > Tris to Quads*.

[image]

Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to unselect everything. Hover over a sphere and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select it. Do this with every sphere and the 2 eyes and then press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them. This will make your editing much easier. If you want to unhide them, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

[image]

Notice that there are these 2 edges shown below that did not cooperate in the Quads conversion. Press <kbd>2</kbd> to go into *Edge Select* mode and just select them manually on each star corner and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

Press <kbd>3</kbd> to go into *Face Select* mode and select these faces and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces*

[image]

Press <kbd>1</kbd> to back into *Vertex Select* mode and select these vertices then go to menu *Edge >* [`Bridge Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) which will create these horizontal faces.

[image]

Hover over this new face area and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to add [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) and scroll your mouse wheel 2 ticks forward to add 3 loop cuts then press click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to put them in without offset. Then fill in the missing faces at the bottom by selecting the vertices as shown and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill a face.

[image]

In the animation below do the following to fill the face at the star corner: (1) Select those 3 vertices and press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge At Center*; (2) Select all vertices around missing face and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill a face; (3) Select those 2 vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd> to split the face so that they become quads; and (4) select those 2 vertices and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Edges* so they also become quads.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, it has removed the wrinkles when using the subdivision. I certainly learn't a lot. However, the shape of the original mesh has been altered. I'm wondering how I can reshape the mesh back to its original shape/silhouette/curvature/volume. Should I use something like proportional editing? I have uploaded another file showing the result after following your steps and applying the subsurf modifier.

Comment: Not sure if the file is uploaded.

Comment: @Brendon there's a smoothing tool in sculpting mode then u can try use the proportional edit to bloat it a bit

Comment: @ Harry McKenzie I tried that, but it's a bit finicky. What about shrinkwrap modifier? I could wrap it to the unquadrified duplicate in some way?